# How to retrieve the month with the least amount of bookings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I working on a little web project and I was wondering what SQL I would need to use find the month with the least amount of bookings.

I have a `Booking` table:

[image]

I have a `Package` table:

[image]

I have a `HolidayMaker` table:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/b3459cd20e4fc795c46305f357f6016e.png]

I think this might have something to do with nested `SELECT` statements, however I am not entirely sure.

Thanks, James. 
:-)

Comment: Step 1, construct a (JOIN) query which returns the bookings with months and their amounts. (GROUP BY perhaps.) Step 2, pick the month with the least amount of bookings.

Comment: "least amount" is this "amount" the number of bookings or by £value?

Comment: what do you mean by "the least amount of bookings" ? are you looking for the least number of booking count or least amount of package price in a month ?

Comment: @Md.MostafizurRahman Sorry for the vague question, it's basically to check how many bookings there are in each month, money will not come into this equation :)

Comment: @Matt  Sorry for the vague question, it's basically to check how many bookings there are in each month, money will not come into this equation :)

Comment: @JamesBarrett, now clear your problem, you can check my answer. hope it will help you. if does not work then just find these syntax for mysql. i tested my query in my MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are interested in seeing results 'only' for months, not taking in account years: (I.e. All reservations from any January, no matter what year):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Bo_Datebooked) as month, COUNT(1) as num_reservations
FROM Booking
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY num_reservations ASC
/* additionality add... 
/* LIMIT 1 */
/* ...to see only the lower result */
```

In case you're concerned in differenciate months from each year (I.e: reseravations from January 2016, reservations from January 2012...):

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(Bo_Datebooked), YEAR(Bo_Datebooked)) as date, COUNT(1) as num_reservations
FROM Booking
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY num_reservations ASC
/* additionality add... 
/* LIMIT 1 */
/* ...to see only the lower result */
```

Warning: any of this won't show you months with 0 reservations!!!

Comment: COUNT(1) counts the number of rows that matches a specified criteria. In this case, in a SELECT with a GROUP BY, counts the items for each month (or month-year). It works the same as COUNT(\*). 
Details about COUNT() function here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp 
Details about COUNT(1) vs COUNT(\*) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Answer (score 2):

Use `MONTHNAME` and `GROUP BY` a `COUNT`.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Bo_Datebooked), COUNT(Booking_ID)
FROM Booking
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Bo_Datebooked)
ORDER BY COUNT(Booking_ID) ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query returns the booking amount for each month:

```
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(Bo_DateBooked, '%Y-%m') AS BookingMonth,
         SUM(Package_Price)                  AS MonthlyAmount
FROM     Booking
JOIN     Package
  ON     Booking.Package_ID = Package.Package_ID
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Bo_DateBooked, '%Y-%m');
```

Using a nested `SELECT`, you can get the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an aggregation with `limit`:

```
select date_format(bo_datebooked, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, count(*)
from booking b
group by date_format(bo_datebooked, '%Y-%m') 
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sql. I test this in my ms sql server. If it's not working just find similar syntax for mysql server. ok ?

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, Bo_Datebooked)), COUNT(Booking_Id) FROM Booking
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, Bo_Datebooked))
ORDER BY COUNT(Booking_Id) ASC
```

Hope this will help you